# If i have a fixed size char array of padded ascii digits which I know refers to an unsigned integer, what is the fastest way to convert it to such?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, atoi

Suppose I have a `char buf[12];` which I know will always have a right justified unsigned number padded on the left with spaces. So, for example: `_________329` (where the `_` stands for space). The fastest way I can think of parsing it is with something like this:

```
while (*buf == ' ') buf++;
atoi(buf);
```

but I was wondering if there was a faster way, particularly with `atoi` given that we know it is unsigned which `atoi` does not assume..

Comment: You cant use a `string`?

Comment: `atoi` skips leading spaces.  Why do you thing your loop will be faster than how it does it?

Comment: @JamesKanze - Perhaps he knows that his numbers are usually less than 6 characters, so it's quicker to start from the end of the string?  Also, 'leading spaces' is probably a call to `isspace()` which is definitely slower than a test for `' '`.

Comment: `_________329` already has 12 characters, so there is no more memory left for the NUL terminator. Are your strings not NUL terminated? Why are you using a `char[12]` instead of a `char[10]` then? An `int` usually has 10 digits. Maybe 5 or 20, but certainly not 11 or 12.

Comment: Obligitory use a profiler comment

Comment: @FredOverflow is right, the largest unsigned `int` you can have is 4294967295 which is 10 digits. If you really need 12 you'll want to use a `uint64_t` or `double`.

Comment: I dont pick the char buf..it is really a long char* that comes to me in a fixed format. I solved the above by using a precached solution to convert into any unsigned N digit number for N <= 10 into.

Comment: @FredOverflow How many characters an int may need depends very heavily on the implementation.  There's no reason why his ints shouldn't be 12 characters.

Comment: @JamesKanze I bet you five virtual dollars that Palace's `int`s are in fact 32 bit :)

Comment: @MarkRansom The largest unsigned int is implementation defined.  In addition to the frequent `65535` and `4294967295`, I've seen `68719476735` and `1099511627775`, and I know that there have been even larger values in the past.  (The old CDC-6000 series had 60 bit words.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the first char is reserved for a "potential sign" and is always "space"? Because otherwise, you would only need a `char[11]` instead of a `char[12]`. Anyway, fixed size allows manual loop unrolling:

```
unsigned parse(const char(&b)[12])
{
    return ((((((((((b[1] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[2] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[3] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[4] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[5] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[6] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[7] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[8] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[9] & 15))
             * 10 + (b[10]& 15);
}
```

Note that the `& 15` trick treats spaces and zeros the same and will work with both ASCII (space = 32, zero = 48) and EBCDIC (space = 48, zero = 240). I haven't checked out other character encodings yet :)

Will this actually be faster or slower than `atoi`? The only way to find out is to measure. But I would probably stay with `atoi` in any case, because using a standard function always improves readability.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this!

Comment: And did you actually gain any speed?

Comment: Yes I did, basically a 2x2 memoization matrix kind of approach.

Comment: Oh by the way...do you have a reference to the & 15 trick? It's quite clever.

Comment: @PalaceChan Nope, thought of it myself :) But I would be surprised if I were the first to come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

First, ask yourself why you're doing this.  If 'buf' was a file of great length, you could suffer from a [Schmiel the Painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html), and if you had a great many decimal digits, you could have problems when multiplying a large number using eg. [GMP](http://gmplib.org) (see the mpz section for signed integer arithmetic)

Second, consider what you know that your standard library does not know.  [Dmitry suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11477872/325514) using a 'fast platform-optimized `strrchr`, but there's nothing that strrchr can do to get around the problem of iterating through the string and `strrchr` actually has additional constraints, like searching for the terminating null character.

You might know some things like:

- Your numbers will never be negative; ie atoi doesn't need to pick up a leading +/- sign.. You've correctly noted this, however, this probably isn't a major factor in the timing.
- Your numbers will be mostly short or mostly long, which would dictate whether you should start looking for spaces at the beginning or end of the string.  Notably, `strrchr` doesn't know the length of the string and hence always reads from the start, as does the implementation of `atoi` that I'm looking at (in Newlib). Your example code also implies a search from the beginning of the string.
- Your numbers will always be in base 10.  This removes a bit of math.
- Your numbers will always fit in an unsigned long.  Yes, this is guaranteed because they're 12 characters, but atoi doesn't know this and will make some attempt to handle errors.   Also, `atoi()` returns a signed integer, so that's something that needs to be addressed in case you ever need a 13-bit number like 1,000,000,000.
- Something else I haven't thought of; but you might.

You should start by **reading the source**. An awful lot can be gained from this simple exercise! I have recently been working with [Newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) and have that downloaded and open, so that's what I'll reference, but GNU's [glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree) and whatever Windows uses will probably be different.

At first glance, I see a simple optimization: `atoi` is just a call to `strtol`, or 'string to long' (int and long are both 32 bits on my platform, 'long long' is necessary to get anything bigger).  The compiler probably optimizes that to a direct call, but it might save us a cycle.  For your ostensibly speed-sensitive application, just call strtol() straight away.  Or rather, call `strtoul`, 'string to unsigned long', since that's what you're doing. Now that we've got a function that doesn't call anything else notable, let's take a look at it. Ignore the reentrancy stuff for now. Careful with the brackets, some ifs have them and the associated elses lack them (which is poor style IMO, I prefer brackets everywhere).

```
unsigned long _strtoul_r
    (struct _reent *rptr, _CONST char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)
{
  register const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char *)nptr;
  register unsigned long acc;
  register int c;
  register unsigned long cutoff;
  register int neg = 0, any, cutlim;

  /*
   * See strtol for comments as to the logic used.
   */
  do {
    c = *s++;
  } while (isspace(c));
  if (c == '-') {
    neg = 1;
    c = *s++;
  } else if (c == '+')
    c = *s++;
    if ((base == 0 || base == 16) &&
    c == '0' && (*s == 'x' || *s == 'X')) {
    c = s[1];
    s += 2;
    base = 16;
  }
  if (base == 0)
    base = c == '0' ? 8 : 10;
  cutoff = (unsigned long)ULONG_MAX / (unsigned long)base;
  cutlim = (unsigned long)ULONG_MAX % (unsigned long)base;
  for (acc = 0, any = 0;; c = *s++) {
    if (isdigit(c))
      c -= '0';
    else if (isalpha(c))
      c -= isupper(c) ? 'A' - 10 : 'a' - 10;
    else
      break;
    if (c >= base)
      break;
    if (any < 0 || acc > cutoff || (acc == cutoff && c > cutlim))
    any = -1;
    else {
      any = 1;
      acc *= base;
      acc += c;
    }
  }
  if (any < 0) {
    acc = ULONG_MAX;
    rptr->_errno = ERANGE;
  } else if (neg)
    acc = -acc;
  if (endptr != 0)
    *endptr = (char *) (any ? (char *)s - 1 : nptr);
  return (acc);
}
```

Starting from the function definition, we notice that there's some reentrancy cruft that can be stripped out if our application is single-threaded.  There's also a char **ptr argument which stores a pointer to the string past the parsed number, which we don't need.   There's also no length definition, so it will have to search for the null character to find the length of the string.

In this application, *s is defined to be a register, which makes sense on my platform but might not on yours.  There's also some other integers defined which we won't need.

In the do/while loop, there's a call to `isspace()` which checks for the space, horizontal tab, newline, vertical tab, feed, and carriage return characters.  You only need space. Also, it starts from the front of the string and works its way back. change that if you've got predominantly small numbers.

Then, we do some base testing stuff.  Base can be 0, allowing for automatic detection of the base (which takes cycles), and if it's 8 or 16 it allows a leading '0's or leading '0x', which we don't need to know or test.

Next, we create 'cutoff' and 'cutlim' variables; you don't need these because ostensibly you don't need range checking.

Finally, we get to the concluding for loop. There's an if\else if\else block which determines the character type and numeric value with `isdigit`, `isalpha`, and `isupper` functions. These incorporate some facy locale-dependent code; it appears that we can assume decimal values which replaces the whole if/else if/else block with a single `c -= 0` statement.

Next, there's some more error checking in `if (c >= base)` which ischeap and might be good to retain.  Recall that C is unsigned, so if *s was, for example, a space (0x20) (which is less than '0', 0x30) this wouuld evaluate to (unsigned)(0x30 - 0x20) = 255 - 10, which is greater than the base (10).  It's not perfect, but it's pretty good and very cheap.

Next, there's some bounds checking in the `if (any...` block, and then we get to the actual meat of the function: `acc *= base; acc += c;`.  There's little we can do to optimize this, but if we had a binary base we could convert this to shifts.  Hopefully you have a fast hardware multiplier on your processor, if this is an Arduino ISR you're in trouble. You may want to look into DSP assembly instructions like multiply-accumulate to speed this up if you've got them.

After the for loop, there's some more error handling and handling of negative numbers which we can also ignore.

So, to summarize, I'd write a new function to handle your special case if you're doing it a lot:

```
unsigned long TwelveCharDecimalStringWithLeadingSpacestoul(char *nptr)
{
    register const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char *)nptr;
    register unsigned long acc;
    register int c, base = 10;

  do {
    c = *s++;
  } while (c == ' ');

  for (acc = 0;; c = *s++) {
    c -= '0';
    if (c >= base) {
      _errno = ERANGE;
      acc = -1;
      break;
    }
    acc *= base;
    acc += c;
  }
  return (acc);
}
```

which takes out the genericity of `atoi` and uses the assumptions that you've made to be a little faster.  However, unless this operation takes place an awful lot, or has to happen extremely fast, you're probably better off with the far simpler, clearer, safer, more flexible, and generally better:

```
unsigned long result = 0;
char *begin = strrchr(buf, ' ');
result = strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);

if (result == 0 && errno == ERANGE)
   // Handle error
```

**EDIT**: I finish writing, and I notice that [FredOverflow has posted a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478809/325514).  Unrolls the loop (I didn't do that, it didn't seem necessary but any loop of known duration can be unrolled if necessary) and does a neat trick with `& 15`, which I have to admit is pretty cool.  However, the above function is still a good demonstration of how to approach the problem of speeding up some standard library calls in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will be faster:

```
char *begin = strrchr(buf, ' ');
atoi(begin ? begin : buf);
```

Assuming the fast platform-optimized standard function strrchr.